# User defined Validations coupling issue

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

Have an API defined that clients will be able to utilize.  Clients will be connected via a variety of means.  One of them is java-to-java.  In this specific case, am having an issue.  Obviously, the API should be as decoupled from the implementation as possible.  I haven't had the chance to test this yet, but won't user defined validations break this model?

I am enabling the Validation via Spring @Validated on the API server-side implementation.  Did not want to put this into @Controller class as that is not the only way into the service (API).

For example, if I have this method defined in the Interface:

```
SomeObject updateOperation( AnInputClass param) ...
```

I can then annotate with JSR-303 validations and still be de-coupled:
    @NonNull
    SomeObject updateOperation( @NonNull AnInputClass param) ...
But if I want custom validation on the various pieces/parts of the input "param", I need to make my own Annotation, **which has an @Constraint(validatedBy) part**  This part will tie to the validation implementation.  The abbreviated form of this would look like:

```
SomeObject updateOperation ( @CheckInput AnInputClass param)... 
...where the annotation is defined as
...
@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckInputValidator.class)   // this is the coupling issue
public @interface CheckInput { ....
```

Since this all happens server-side, there should be no need to have Java clients have to have this CheckInputValidator class; however, I am seeing no options.   First, I *like* having the validations in the API - they tell users what will be validated.  If I could break the dependency and move the validation down to the implementation that would seem like an acceptable tradeoff.  However that results in the exception below so it seems like I am stuck.  Can anyone help?

```
javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: Only the root method of an 
overridden method in an inheritance hierarchy may be annotated with parameter 
constraints, but there are parameter constraints defined at all of the 
following overridden methods
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer myself, I should have realized this earlier!

All I needed to do was to use the "@Valid" annotation in the interface/API layer.  Then, making sure the @Target annotation on the User Defined / Custom annotation has "TYPE" defined, apply the @CheckInput annotation to the desired class and everything works perfectly!